# Is $P(X + Y \leq c, Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c)$ regardless of X and Y being independent?

Tags: probability

For conditional independence, when $X,Y$ are independent, then we can write
$$
P(X + Y \leq c | Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c)
$$

If they are not independent, then we have
$$
P(X + Y \leq c | Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c | Y = y)
$$

where we can't drop the conditional.

Now I am trying to think about the joint distribution case. If they are independent, then I believe
$$
P(X + Y \leq c, Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c)
$$

But what about the case where they are dependent?

Is the above still true? I can't think of why it wouldn't be true.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X+Y\le c,Y=y)=\mathsf{P}(X+y\le c,Y=y),
$$
and if $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X+y\le c,Y=y)=\mathsf{P}(X+y\le c)\times \mathsf{P}(Y=y).
$$

Comment: Wait, is $P(X + Y \leq c | Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c)$? even if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent?

Comment: If so, couldn't we do
$$
P(X + Y \leq c, Y = y) = P(X + Y \leq c | Y = y) P(Y = y) = P(X + y \leq c)P(Y = y)
$$

which gives your last expression but there's no presumption of independence?

Comment: No. The equality in the first comment doesn't hold when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent because the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ depends on $y$.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but in the answer below yours, it seems to imply once when set the $Y$ on the LHS of the inequality, then we would already have accounted for the conditioning, and hence we can then drop it. Is that not true?

Comment: No, we cannot drop it. For example, consider the case when $X=Y$...